# using R.groupWith (ramda)

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm trying to group the following array acc to `dateValue`, but can't seem to get it to work. What am I missing here?

```js
const dates = [
  {"id":83,"dateValue":"2017-05-24"},
  {"id":89,"dateValue":"2017-05-28"},
  {"id":91,"dateValue":"2017-05-25"},
  {"id":78,"dateValue":"2017-05-24"},
  {"id":84,"dateValue":"2017-05-25"}
]

const groups = R.groupWith(R.eqProps('dateValue'),dates)

console.log(groups)
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ramda/latest/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

I've included a [link to ramda repl with this code loaded](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20dates%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A83%2CdateValue%3A%222017-05-24%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A89%2CdateValue%3A%222017-05-28%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A91%2CdateValue%3A%222017-05-25%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A78%2CdateValue%3A%222017-05-24%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A84%2CdateValue%3A%222017-05-25%22%7D%0A%5D%0A%0AR.groupWith%28R.eqProps%28%27dateValue%27%29%2Cdates%29)

expected result:

```
[ [ { dateValue: "2017-05-24", id: 83 },
    { dateValue: "2017-05-24", id: 78 } ],
  [ { dateValue: "2017-05-28", id: 89 } ],
  [ { dateValue: "2017-05-25", id: 91 } ],
  [ { dateValue: "2017-05-25", id: 84 } ] ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several differences between [`groupBy`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) and [`groupWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupWith).

- `groupBy` accepts a function which yields a grouping key for a single item.  `groupWith` accepts a binary predicate that says whether two items match.
- `groupBy` collects all items into single collections.  `groupWith` only collects matching itemss which are *consecutive*.
- `groupBy` returns an object that maps those keys to the list of matching items.  `groupWith` returns a list of lists of (again consecutive) matching items.

It's that second point which is tripping you up.  You probably want `groupBy`:

```
R.groupBy(R.prop('dateValue'))(dates)
// or
R.compose(R.values, R.groupBy(R.prop('dateValue')))(dates);
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?const%20dates%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A83%2C%22dateValue%22%3A%222017-05-24%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A89%2C%22dateValue%22%3A%222017-05-28%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A91%2C%22dateValue%22%3A%222017-05-25%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A78%2C%22dateValue%22%3A%222017-05-24%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%22id%22%3A84%2C%22dateValue%22%3A%222017-05-25%22%7D%0A%5D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20R.groupBy%28R.prop%28%27dateValue%27%29%29%28dates%29%0A%2F%2F%20or%0AR.compose%28R.values%2C%20R.groupBy%28R.prop%28%27dateValue%27%29%29%29%28dates%29%3B)**.

Comment: Aah! "consecutive"! Is that mentioned somewhere? Didn't see it. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Where in the docs does it specify the consecutive consideration for `groupWith`, though? I'm not seeing it in http://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupWith.

Comment: It doesn't say so, although the examples should make it clear.  A Pull Request to fix it would be welcome.